# How to use a results of a SQL Server query in another query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am fairly new to SQL Server and trying to do something that seems like it ought to be fairly basic, but I must be missing a significant concept.

**First, here is the story:**

- I have table X which contains line items from orders
- I have table Y which contains the orders themselves

I want to divide the number of line items by the number of orders, thus generating the number of line items on an average order.

**I've tried a few options:**

1. I tried joining the two tables together, and then dividing the count() of X by the count of Y. Unfortunately, by X to Y it creates an entry for every Y, so the result of the division is one.

   ```
   select count(x) / count (y) 
   from x 
   join y
   ```
2. I tried making half of the select statement "distinct" by trying to count "distinct" orders but not distinct line items. Turns out you can't make half the select statement be distinct.

   ```
   select count(x) / distinct count (y) 
   from x 
   join y
   ```
3. I tried making a new table, and outputting the sum of the number of orders into the new table. Then I tried to go divide the number of line items by the value of that table. That doesn't work unless I join the tables together, which returns me to the original problem.

   ```
   select count(x) / temptable
   from x
   join temptable
   ```
4. I tried looking up how to output a `SQL` statement to a variable so I could then use that variable for the division, but got nowhere on that.
5. I have read diligently through lots of stack overflow posts that hint at this issue but don't actually resolve it.

Any help will be sincerely appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at [AVG()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) ?

Comment: Yes, I tried using avg but my understanding is that AVG will just average the one column and I need to divide the one sum by the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is without a subquery:

```
select count(*) * 1.0 / count(distinct order_id)
from line_items
```

This assumes that all orders have at least one line item.  If this is not the case, you can do:

```
select count(*) * 1.0 / (select count(*) from orders)
from line_items
```

Or, if you don't like subqueries in `select` clauses, you can use a join instead:

```
select count(li.line_item_id)*1.0/count(distinct o.order_id)
from orders o left outer join
     line_items li
     on o.order_id = li.order_id
```

Comment: oh, this works too! Thanks, I learned new things from both answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT AVG(1.0 * line_item_count) 
FROM (
  SELECT order_id, COUNT(*) as line_item_count
  FROM line_items
  GROUP BY order_id
) line_item_counts
```

Comment: Please modify this to be `avg(1.0*line_item_count)`.  Almost no one wants integer averages, although that is what MSSQL does by default.

Comment: oh! i didn't realize you can "nest" select statements, let me give that a shot, thanks.

Comment: @ZacCramer: the technical term for this is a "derived table"

Comment: And as @GordonLinoff posted, it isn't entirely necessary in this case.  But it's certainly good to know!